# What's the difference between actual arguments, format arguments, dummy arguments and actual and formal parameters?

Tags: c

I think some mentioned above are just synonyms but which ones? Also correct me if I'm wrong: In a function lets say the main function, the data between parenthesis is parameters/arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing values to a function has two points of view:

A function itself has a parameter (or formal parameter), when it is compiled. I. e. …

```
void f( int a )
{
  …
}
```

… has the (formal) parameter `a`.

When the function is called at run-time, there is a value that `a` represents. This is the argument (actual parameter):

```
f( 5 )
```

Here `5` is the argument (actual parameter).

So the call maps the argument/actual parameter to the formal parameter.

In C in some situations you can pass a variable number of arguments to a function. This is, if the function has an open parameter list:

```
f( int a, ... )
```

In many cases the first parameter is a format string that needs additional arguments. I. e.:

```
printf( "%d items", 5 );
```

In this case `"%d items"` is a format string (format argument) that tells the function to insert a string representation of the second argument ahead of `" items"`.

But a variable number of arguments does not limit to format strings. I. e. the following examples are all (formally) valid calls:

```
f( int a, ... ) { … }

f( 5 );
f( 6, 2, 3 )
```

I think, dummy arguments/parameters has different meanings. It can be an parameter (and therefore an argument in a call) that isn't used inside the function. It can be an optional parameter, that gets a default value, if there is no argument for it in the call. (This concept does not exist in C, but in other programming languages.)

Comment: With `void f( int a )` and `f(5.3)`, what might you call the 5.3 given to the function versus 5 that was passed to `f()`?

Comment: This is out of scope of the Q. However, it might be a help for you to read section 3.3 and 6.5.2.2 of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

A **parameter** is defined in the function definition.It is a placeholder for the arguments during function execution.

```
void printMessage(string message){  //message is a parameter. 

 }
```

An **argument** is a value passed to a function when the function is called.

```
printMessage("Hello World"); //"Hello World" is an argument.
```

Though someone consider argument as a parameter.

Comment: To be more precise, a pointer to `"Hello WOrld"` is the actual argument, not `msg.` The latter one would be a call by reference that does not exist in C.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have correct my answer. Thank you.